# If I used a fair coin flip to determine bets on binary outcomes, will I be correct half the time?

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples

Suppose I am betting on binary outcomes, lets say randomly drawing a red ball from an urn with only red and yellow balls That is, I say either "red" or "yellow", then a ball is drawn from the urn, and I win the bet if I am correct.

> If I choose to say "red" or "yellow" on the basis of flipping a fair
>   coin  will I be correct half the time?

Assume the coin is independent of the distribution of balls in the urn, as well as of the process of choosing a ball from the urn (because random and Its weird to have a coin flip related to this)

---

My attempt at this is as follows. (In what follows suppose I guess red when the coin is heads)

Suppose there are $N$ balls in the urn, $K$ of which are red. Then the probability of a red ball being drawn is $\frac{K}{N}$.

Define a random variable $X$ such that $X=1$ if I win the bet (I guess correctly) and $X=0$ if I guess incorrectly. Then the question reduces to finding the expected value of $X$ (when the probability that $X=1$ is calculated according to the betting strategy).

The expected value of $X$ is $$1\cdot P(X=1) = P(X=1) = \\.5P(Red\vert Heads) + .5P(Yellow\vert Tails) = .5P(RED)+.5(P(Tails) = .5$$

So I would be correct half the time.

---

> Could someone tell me how I could formally derive the probability of
>   being correct, i.e. $P(X=1)$. That is, how can I mathematically show
>   that $$P(X=1) = .5P(Red\vert Heads) + .5P(Yellow\vert Tails)$$

I guess I would need to define a random variable for the outcome of the urn, and a random variable for the outcome of the coin flip, find the joint distribution of these random variables, and then $P(Correct)=P(Red,Heads) + P(Yellow, tails)$?

By independence though I guess $P(Red,Heads) =P(RED)\cdot P(Heads)) and similar for tails, which gives the formula.

Comment: Not  all binary events have equal probability.  My lottery ticket will either win or lose today....but not with equal probability.

Comment: The binary even doesn't need to have equal probability for betting on a coin flip to be make me correct half the time? At least, I didn't assume in the question that the binary event has equal probability, but perhaps I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: No, sorry.  What you said is correct.  sticking with my lottery ticket, you'll be right half the time regardless of whether I win or lose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will win with probability $\dfrac KN$ half of the time and win with probability $\dfrac{N-K}N$ the other half. On average, $\dfrac12$.

Said differently, whatever the outcome, you will choose this outcome half of the time.

Comment: Thank you. Any chance you could include how I could formally derive the the probability of winning?

Comment: @user106860: $1/2\ K/N+1/2\ (N-K)/N=1/2$.